# Reliably counting bytes written by fwrite when disk is full

Tags: c, buffer, fwrite

Does anyone know a reliable way to count how many bytes have actually
been written, using C standard I/O (`fwrite`), in a disk-full situation?

I’ve had a lot of trouble getting this to work. The problem seems to be
that `fwrite` is buffered, and it sometimes thinks that it has written
more bytes than the device can actually accept.

Using a small buffer, the same size as the device blocks, `fwrite` would
report it had written a full buffer when it actually had not, so the
count ended up being one block more than was correct. I fixed that by
testing for an error and only adding to the total if there was no error.

But then, with a larger buffer, `fwrite` would write a partial buffer,
and I would fail to count that. So I checked for a partial write, adding
and breaking out of the loop. Ended up with the following program
(reduced to MCVE):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//#define BUF_SIZE 4096
#define BUF_SIZE 8192
//#define BUF_SIZE 16384

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long ct = 0;
    size_t written;
    unsigned char *buf;

    buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    memset(buf, 0xFF, BUF_SIZE);

    while (1) {
        written = fwrite(buf, 1, BUF_SIZE, stdout);
        if (written < BUF_SIZE) {
            ct += written;
            break;
        }
        fflush(stdout);
        if (ferror(stdout))
            break;
        ct += written;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%llu bytes written\n", ct);

    return 0;
}
```

The device has 4k blocks, and either 68k or 72k free. I tried buffer
sizes of 4k, 8k, and 16k.

And the darned thing *still* doesn’t work. When there’s 72k free and I
use an 8k buffer, it writes 72k, then thinks it wrote another 4k and
adds that.

I suppose I could just use a buffer size that’s equal to the block size.
But I’m not even sure that would work reliably.

Does anyone know how to make it work in all cases? I’m thinking it might
be best to just bypass the buffering issue entirely and use POSIX I/O
instead (`open` and `write`).

---

Edit: [nsilent22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5128826)’s suggestion worked correctly and reduced
the loop to two lines:

```
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    ...
    while ((written = fwrite(buf, 1, BUF_SIZE, stdout)) > 0)
        ct += written;
```

Comment: Hm... that's a nice problem. That's a place where the stdio API breaks which makes sense: In UNIX, files are not supposed to give non-fatal writing errors and applications do not generally expect to get an ENOSPC.

Comment: Is using `setbuf` with NULL an option?

Comment: @nsilent22: Hmm, hadn’t thought of that. It seems to work correctly with that. Given that I’m writing a big buffer anyway, I suppose it wouldn’t affect performance. Thanks for the suggestion. Want to post it as an answer? It might be the best solution.

Comment: Posted. Hope it helps.

Comment: If you want some system testing, the the buffered C libnrary is the wrong tool; just bypass it and use system functions, write synchronously, etc. You still might have some uncertainity. If that is for production code, you should not really care; the data written is currupt anyway, it doesn't care where in the file that happened (for an error report the "why" is sufficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `setbuf` function with NULL parameter as a buffer. It will turn off stream buffering.

Answer (score 1):

> *I’m thinking it might be best to just bypass the buffering issue entirely and use POSIX I/O instead (`open` and `write`).*

You have the solution!  Buffering does get in your way.  `fread` returns the number of elements correctly written to the stream, but part of the stream might not have been flushed yet, and the `fflush()` may subsequently fail if the device is full.  There is no portable way to find out how many bytes weren't flushed.

You could `fclose()` the file, reopen it (in binary mode) and seek to the end to find out, but it would be simpler to use low level Posix I/O in the first place.

Setting the stream buffering to unbuffered should work but might cause a significant loss of performance if the file is large.

You indeed are going to write large amounts of data to attempt to overwrite a hard drive. I wrote a utility like this a long time ago... Definitely do use unbuffered strams and use the low level Posix API with a large buffer whose size should be a power of 2 and that you fill with random defeat OS or hardware algorithms that may try to compress or otherwise share your data blocks.  Any pseudo random polynomial will do, but do change the buffer contents between each write.

Note that if your system is 32 bits, you may run into a file size limitation at 2G or 4G. There might also be such a limitation due to the File System used.  You can work around these by creating multiple files.

Comment: The file will be *very* large; I’ll be using this to wipe a 300-GB drive. But if I’m writing a 4k, 8k, or 16k buffer, would turning off stream buffering slow things down? My impression is that buffering is mostly helpful if you’re doing a lot of small writes. And wouldn’t using POSIX `write` have the same effect?

Comment: @TomZych: You are aware that this will not necessarily "wipe" as you think? Modern HDDs - and much worse SSDs use replacement algorithms which do not necessarily write the block(s) the previous data was. And they also have internal spare blocks for defective blocks and SSDs additionally to allow writing a "full" medium, wear-levelling, etc. Use mechanical/thermal wiping or (if supported) the "secure erase" feature for the drive. In general store sensitive data only encrypted. That way you don't need to erase.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, I’ve read Gutmann’s paper, thanks. Just doing what I can with a drive I don’t want to destroy yet. And it was a nice opportunity to practice using C, which I don’t use much these days.

Comment: This was all useful but I was more interested in the question of whether it was possible with standard I/O, so nsilent22’s answer was more on point. The unbuffered standard I/O turned out to be about as fast as the POSIX I/O. Thanks.

Comment: @TomZych: *The unbuffered standard I/O turned out to be about as fast as the POSIX I/O.* You were lucky, `fwrite` mapped its request to `write` calls directly. Not all C libraries do this for unbuffered streams.